# getting error Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am using ai to write solidity contract and below is the contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

   // Import the A2AToken contract from the A2A Token file
import "./a2atoken.sol";

// The A2AN contract allows users to deposit and withdraw A2A tokens
contract A2AN {
    // The address of the A2A token contract
    A2AToken private a2aToken;

    // The event that is emitted when tokens are deposited
    event Deposited(address indexed depositor, uint256 amount);

    // The event that is emitted when tokens are withdrawn
    event Withdrawn(address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    // The constructor initializes the A2A token contract
   
    // The deposit function allows anyone to deposit tokens into the contract
    function deposit(uint256 amount) external {
        // Transfer the tokens to this contract
        a2aToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

        // Emit the Deposited event
        emit Deposited(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    // The withdraw function allows anyone to withdraw tokens from the contract
    function withdraw(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        // Transfer the tokens from this contract to the specified address
        a2aToken.transfer(to, amount);

        // Emit the Withdrawn event
        emit Withdrawn(to, amount);
    }
}
```

---

when i try to test with mumbai test net for the deposit of tokens i an getting error

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "blockHash": "0x0ae759ea3a5ad071120dab7524db67b80e48efc81153b9f7c525dcfc5eb1038a", "blockNumber": 43432596, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": 1033238, "effectiveGasPrice": 1500000016, "from": "0xa6fac03ee4b8612a6239769e58a55dd53021a633", "gasUsed": 26990, "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000800000000000000000000100000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000080000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000", "status": false, "to": "0xa57268547cb3f8bf7acb65c5284c2e0dce3b4b09", "transactionHash": "0x4cb922dc7e8b1bbafb2b8958f9d7f77e5cf5cd7f14c553ef5f6df48edd991599", "transactionIndex": 9, "type": "0x2", "events": { "0": { "address": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010", "blockNumber": 43432596, "transactionHash": "0x4cb922dc7e8b1bbafb2b8958f9d7f77e5cf5cd7f14c553ef5f6df48edd991599", "transactionIndex": 9, "blockHash": "0x0ae759ea3a5ad071120dab7524db67b80e48efc81153b9f7c525dcfc5eb1038a", "logIndex": 16, "removed": false, "id": "log_70fb6deb", "returnValues": {}, "signature": null, "raw": { "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024d2260b320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000564f13516cdb8bc7a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035779b0356e11abfded100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000564f11044a7ad8a7a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035779b037bb340cb10d1", "topics": [ "0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010", "0x000000000000000000000000a6fac03ee4b8612a6239769e58a55dd53021a633", "0x000000000000000000000000be188d6641e8b680743a4815dfa0f6208038960f" ] } } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of clarity on the question, I can suggest you few checkpoints.

1. Is the `a2aToken` deployed on Mumbai, if yes, are you providing the right address?
2. does the `msg.sender` have the correct amount of balance?
3. are you approving this `A2AN` contract to spend the tokens on behalf of the `msg.sender`.

The 3rd point is most likely to be the case, as many people miss this part. You need to call the approve function on the token contract with this A2AN contract's address before calling the deposit function.

I would suggest studying a bit about solidity before directly copying AI-generated code and then solving errors.

Comment: Thanks. No 3 addressed the concern. yes giving the approval to contractr address was the requirement and after that it started working thanks

Comment: actua code has issue with token address updation in contract. i created new code and approval of new contract address has been updated and after that code started to work and here is the updated code.

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract DepositContract {
    // Address of the a2a token contract
    address public a2aTokenAddress;
    
    // Address of the contract owner
    address public owner;
    
    // Mapping to store the deposited token balances of each user
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    
    // Event emitted when a user deposits tokens
    event Deposit(address indexed user, uint256 amount);

Comment: // Event emitted when the contract owner withdraws tokens
    event Withdrawal(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    
    // Modifier to restrict certain functions to the contract owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }
    
    // Constructor - sets the a2a token address and contract owner
    constructor(address _a2aTokenAddress) {
        a2aTokenAddress = _a2aTokenAddress;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

Comment: // Function to deposit a2a tokens into the contract
    function deposit(uint256 _amount) external {
        // Transfer the tokens from the user to the contract
        IERC20(a2aTokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

Comment: // Update the user's balance
        balances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        
        // Emit the deposit event
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

Comment: // Function to allow the contract owner to withdraw deposited tokens
    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        // Check if the contract has enough balance
        require(_amount <= IERC20(a2aTokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this)), "Insufficient balance in the contract");
        
        // Transfer the tokens from the contract to the owner
        IERC20(a2aTokenAddress).transfer(owner, _amount);
        
        // Update the user's balance
        balances[owner] -= _amount;

Comment: // Emit the withdrawal event
        emit Withdrawal(owner, _amount);
    }
}

Comment: Hey @siliconbee the comments are confusing, please post a new question, or edit the same question if you have further queries. Also mark the answer as correct answer if it solved your problem.